# SWRevealViewController Delegate not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, swrevealviewcontroller

I have implemented a side menu app using `SWRevealViewController` and its working fine. In my `FrontViewController` I want to load a sub view. And when I click the reveal toggle button I want to remove that sub view. Because If I open that sub view and without closing that if I clicked the revealtoggle button it gose to the side menu. And If I select the same menu item above `FrontViewcontroller` load with the subview also (previously it has not closed). So How can I remove this sub view when the side menu appear. I did something like this. But this delegate not firing in my `ViewController`

```
- (void)revealController:(SWRevealViewController *)revealController willMoveToPosition:(FrontViewPosition)position
{

    if(mapon==1)
       {
          [MapView removeFromSuperview];
          mapon=0;
       }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: are you added **SWRevealViewControllerDelegate** in in your class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following line in programmatically

```
self.revealViewController.delegate = self;
```

additional [reference](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/152)

Comment: I also faced the same issue on my project , after that I realize and modify my work , your question is useful for future I given the upvote also , have a nice day friend